# Java how to add Component on Panel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning java and I start from beginning:)

I want to draw line on Panel but I cant

it's my code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    public Window(){    
        setSize(600,600); 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container pow = getContentPane(); 
    Component k = new Test();           
    pow.add(k); 

    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    p1.setBounds(40, 40, 520, 520);
    p1.setBackground(Color.white);
    pow.add(p1);    
}
}
```

and Panel class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JPanel{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(30, 50, 30, 550);
    g.drawLine(30, 550, 550, 550);

    g.drawLine(30, 50, 20, 60);
    g.drawLine(30, 50, 40, 60);

    g.drawLine(550, 550, 540, 540);
    g.drawLine(550, 550, 540, 560);
}

}
```

and main

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Window mo = new Window();
    mo.setVisible(true);
}
```

Why my component is under Panel?
Sory it's my code

Comment: `Panel` and `Component` is AWT, `JPanel` and `JComponent` is Swing. AWT does not use `paintComponent` but `paint`. Switch the AWT classes to the Swing ones or `paintComponent` to `paint` and it _might_ work.

Comment: Post the complete code, so that we can paste it in our IDE and test it. And learn how to use layout managers.

Comment: If your class extends an AWT `Panel`, there is no `paintComponent` method, so any painting would cease to show, since you're not actually overriding anything

Answer (score 1):

- The contentPane uses a BorderLayout as its default layout.
- When you add a component to a BorderLayout container without specifying where, it gets added BorderLayout.CENTER.
- This will then cover up any other components previously added to the same location.

Solution:

- Read up on and experiment with using other layout managers. Check [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).
- Don't setBounds or use null layouts.

Answer (score 1):

`Panel` and `Component` is AWT, `JPanel` and `JComponent` is Swing. AWT does not use `paintComponent` but `paint`. Switch the AWT classes to the Swing ones or `paintComponent` to `paint` and it might work.

This is why adding `@Override` to overriding methods is a good idea, as it tells you that `paintComponent` is not a method of `Component`.

Also you are adding both the component and the panel to the same container. Put the component in the panel.

```
p1.add(k); // yes (add this to your code)
pow.add(k); // no (remove this from your code)
pow.add(p1); // previous would get covered
```